# react-native-linkdin-login is not working in ios?

Tags: react-native, linkedin-api, react-native-ios

I am using react-native-linkdin-login library to support linkding sigin in my application.It is working properly in android but in iOS it always ask to download an application rather than application already exist in device and redirect to the APP store. When I open and login to linkdin account, I can't come back to my react-native application, with user profile details. 
Give me any suggestion as soon as possible.

```
async componentWillMount() {
LinkedinLogin.init(
    [
    'r_emailaddress',
    'r_basicprofile'
    ]
);
```

}

```
async handleLinkedinLogin(){
LinkedinLogin.login().then((user) => {
    alert("linkdin");
    this.setState({ user : user });
    this.getUserProfile();
}).catch((e) => {
    var err = JSON.parse(e.description);
    alert("ERROR: " + err.errorMessage);
    alert('Error', e);
});
return true;
```

}

```
getUserProfile(user) {
LinkedinLogin.getProfile().then((data) => {
    const userdata = Object.assign({}, this.state.user, data);
    this.setState({ user: userdata });
    const  Email = userdata.emailAddress;
    const  Fullname = userdata.firstName+' '+userdata.lastName;
    const SocialAppId = userdata.id;
    const SignupType = 'Linkedin';
    alert("Please wait....")
    this.socialLogin(Fullname,Email,'null',SignupType);

}).catch((e) => {
   alert(e);
});
```

}

Comment: what actually happens once you log in ?

Comment: I can't come back to my application after login to linkdin in ios. I don't get any response or error. It always ask me to download application whether I have already downloaded in ios or not.

Comment: you need to add url schemes to your app info plist, that way the sdk can detect if app is installed or not.

Comment: I have already added in my info.plist
                     <dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
   <string>Editor</string>
   <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
   <array>
    <string>li{YOUR_APP_ID_GOES_HERE}</string>
   </array>
  </dict>

Comment: it asks to download the app within your app? could you share your project code somewhere so that i can see the implementation in ios as well ?